# Jquery and Chrome returns an error with iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

i wrote that simple function and it's works well but when i test it on chrome with javascript console it return this error:
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.mydomine.com/currentpage from frame with URL http://www.iframedomine.com/page. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
can be fixed in some way?

that is how i generate iframe

```
this.frame = function(url, w, h) {
    this.inizialize();      
    this.iframe = $(document.createElement("iframe")).attr("src", url).attr("frameborder", '0');
    this.resize(w, h );
    this.box.html(this.iframe); 
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/frame3.htm